# How to download PHP extensions for Mac OS X

Tags: php, xcode, macos

I recently purchased a Mac to do my LAMP development. However, coming from Debian, using the apt-get tool to download PHP extensions was surprisingly easy but doesn't exist on my Mac. After reading up on multiple forums, it seems one needs to download Xcode and use ports to do so, OR, download the binaries and compile them. So my question is, what is the best tool to use in order to get all these extensions (`php5-mysql`, `php5-gd`, `libapache2-mod-php5`, `php5-curl` etc).

Note: I am using the default PHP installed on my Mac which apparently doesn't come with many extensions or support for them.

Comment: you can try out [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) if you are looking for a easy fix.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer to setup my environment from scratch without all the additional bloat you get from MAMP. Good suggestion but just not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. You can download [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) first and then use [MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/) to download/install/enable php and each extension. This is the same approach we use to setup our LAMP development environment on our MacBook Pros at work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to MacPorts, there's also [Link](https://brew.sh) which has the same approach